# selecting lines based on regex [batch]

Tags: regex, batch-file

i want to select the word containing `grp_` but not `grp_policy` from iam_property.txt

when i do this

```
set file_iam_property="iam_property.txt"
findstr /r "^grp_" %file_iam_property%
```

it returns all the lines in the file because my regex matches all the lines.

content of **iam_property.txt**

```
grp_testgroup1="grp_testgroup1.json"
grp_testgroup2="grp_testgroup2.json"
grp_policy_testpolicy1="grpPolicy_testpolicy1.json"
grp_policy_testpolicy2="grpPolicy_testpolicy2.json"
```

What changes should i make so that i get lines with  `grp_` and not `grp_policy`, the rest part of the line is variable so i cant apply regex on that part, for eg in `grp_testgroup1`  `testgroup1` is variable.

in other words, i want grp_something to be selected but not grp_something_otherthing to be selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex solve your problem:

```
findstr /R "^grp_[^_]*=" %file_iam_property%
```

That is, you want not another `_` before the next `=`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex,

```
grp_(?!policy)
```

It uses the concept of Negative Lookahead.

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iM7hI5/1)

Comment: sry but this is slightly limited approach as in it will always not select `grp_policy` but suppose i have some other word say `grp_access_xyz` then i again need to check for it, i was hoping for a solution that decides on the basis of number of  underscores.

Comment: also i am sry but that doesnt seem to work in batch, though it is working in the demo you suggested. i used this :: 
`findstr /r "^grp_(?!policy)" %file_iam_property%`

Comment: @SubhamTripathi you don't want `grp_policy` to get selected, but want `grp_access_xyz` to get selected, right ? current regex does that. Please update your question with all cases of your input and expected output.

Comment: i only need words having `grp_<something>` to be selected but not `grp_<something>_<otherthing>` to be selected, i hope i am able to make myself clear, thanx :)

Comment: solution of Aacini worked for me ,, thanks for your effort ! :)